# Charging "hesitation" with Pixel

Tags: charging, google-pixel

Here's an odd bit of behavior I'm seeing from my refurbished Pixel:

When I plug it in using the rapid charger that came with it, it at first immediately shows as charging. Then stops less than a second later. Then starts less than a second after that. Stops. (This may repeat five or six times.) Then finally goes to "Charging Rapidly".

It never fails to start charging, nor do I see this from other chargers which, admittedly, don't have the same amperage and so don't kick things up to rapid charging.

Normal? A minor quirk? Or have I got a defective model<sup>1</sup>?

Notes:

- I did not see this with my original Pixel; only with the refurb
- This is the charger and cable that came with the original
- None of the other chargers I have have enough wattage to kick the Pixel into "Charge Rapidly" mode
- It doesn't always do it, but I saw it stop-and-start a dozen times, once

<sup>1</sup> Again! I'm on my second unit because the first suddenly stopped recognizing the headphone jack and the microphone stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Normal? A minor quirk? Or have I got a defective model?

- Not normal - it's not the expected behaviour
- It is more likely a quirk , being a one time occurrence , not noticed since nor on your previous device

**What *may* have caused it?**

Firstly, being a one off occurrence, it is *non – reproducible* ruling out further investigations to establish the reason.  My *best guess* is this :

- From [Andrew's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/143053/131553) , to a related question, the *charging speed* indication is

> ....based on power (in milliWatt) it receives. As shown on the commit log, "[Charging speed based on voltage](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0c859ae9c76db756ba898508a8dc2d92d86e9096%5E%21/)", from the same [config.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0c859ae9c76db756ba898508a8dc2d92d86e9096/packages/Keyguard/res/values/config.xml) file,

```
<!-- Threshold in micro watts below which a charger is rated as "slow"; 1A @ 5V -->
<integer name="config_chargingSlowlyThreshold">5000000</integer>
<!-- Threshold in micro watts above which a charger is rated as "fast"; 1.5A @ 5V  -->
<integer name="config_chargingFastThreshold">7500000</integer>
```

> - Charging slowly: < 5W
> - Charging: 5W - 7.5W
> - Charging rapidly: > 7.5W

- In your case, the *hesitation* you refer to , indicates that *power received by the device varied* casuing it to fluctuate between *Charging -stop- charging rapidly* . This may have been caused by loose contact of the USB (on either end ),  pocket lint or dirt preventing proper contact or power fluctuations at source ( voltage fluctuations ).

**Edit:** Note that that difference between Charging upper limit ( = 7.5 W ) and Charging rapidly ( > 7.5 W ) is borderline (unlike Charging slowly  < 5 W), so intermittent poor connection or marginal fluctuation in input power is enough to have caused this

**Next steps**

- You would need to pay attention to see if it happens again, which then would be a cause for concern as reported in [Google forums - Pixel and Charging Problem](https://support.google.com/pixelirstlyphone/forum/AAAAb4-OgUs19Fmb1raI7w/?hl=by) and elsewhere on Internet. Solutions offered there have mixed results
- If these solutions, don't help, my suggestion would be to change the cable and charger  (see related question  at bottom ) - simply because , they are more likely to fail rather than the device itself being the culprit ( probability wise , from experience  and information on Internet)

**Should this behaviour be  a cause for worry?** -  No. Since it has not been observed since.  If I were in your place, I would anyway buy, spare accessories , just to have peace of mind and use the current ones as back up (doesn't hurt to have spares) , especially it being a top end device.

Related [How to select a Non OEM USB Type C charger or cable for my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/175876/131553)

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer* I've owned a Nexus 6p for a year and had it replaced once due to charging/WiFi issue. I experienced a similar situation to what you're describing here with the "flicker charge"(It can be really annoying when the power save notification flickers).

What appeared to resolve my issue was when I uninstalled some recently downloaded apps. Mind you they were some silly games/ utility apps(Twilight). **Regardless** I suggest speaking with a representative. They were very understanding and accommodating when I interacted with them for my issue.

Good luck all