# Can I replace Huawei 40W supercharger with third party charger but still provide supercharging feature?

Tags: charging, huawei

Can I replace the Huawei 40W supercharger with a third-party charger but still provide a supercharging feature? I don't know what's those fancy things, but electronic isn't rocket science, but I tried to connect a general 45W charger (non-Huawei), my mate 20 pro only show "quick charging", anyone has an idea why?

Comment: According to some specs I found the Huawei charger provides 40W at 10V: 10V/ 4A. I am not sure if this is provided via USB-PD or a proprietary implementation. What voltage levels + ampere does your 45watt charger provide? Also make sure you are using an active USB-C cable that supports that much ampere.

Comment: I am using this one: https://www.momax.net/product/one-plug-65w-3-port-gan-charger/

Comment: Assuming your Huawei phone only supports charging using voltages up to 10V this charger can only provide 9V at 3A = 27 Watt. The other voltage levels are higher than 10V. But as a first test I would use the USB-C cable from the Huawei charger and use it with that charger just to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

There are three parts to any charging system other than the old 5V,2A charging :

- The charging algorithm, which dictates the power to be drawn at various stages of battery charging. It runs on the device incorporated in OS, including low level changes at kernel level. Note that these are proprietary and hence the sales pitch for different OEMs. (See the [charging algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ADGt.png)
  ([Source](https://goughlui.com/2016/05/29/review-teardown-anker-powercore-10050-a1310-qc2-0-power-bank/)
  ) of an Anker power bank to get a sense of how complex it can be).
- The charger which responds to the requests made by the device and varies voltage or current or both as desired by the algorithm.
- USB cable that is capable of carrying the power across from charger to the device. This is the easiest to change, if you know the power requirements.

Unless these three are perfectly aligned, you can't get the desired charging performance. That's why OEMs always insist on using their chargers and cables. Without getting into the specifics of the third party charger you are using (non Huawei), it's obvious that it lacks the capability to meet the demands made by the algorithm. Being a 45 W charger, the device does recognize that it is providing high power and hence displays "quick charging" but cannot super charge.you will get the same results even if you try with any non Huawei charger rated say at 80 or 100W.

Related

1. [Android phone "charging slowly": How to make it faster](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/143031/131553)
2. [Charging "hesitation" with Pixel](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174265/131553)

Comment: Nowadays all three parts are covered by the USB power delivery spec 3.0. But it seems like Huawei still uses a  proprietary charge system as the 10V indicate which is not included by the USB PD spec.

Comment: @Robert 1.it's the implementation of specs in hardware we are discussing 2. I am not updated with latest Huawei tech but in the past they always implemented their own standards 3. Even Pixel which uses USB specs has [it's own share of problems in choosing third party chargers](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/175877/131553) 4. USB PD certification costs money, one more reason for OEMs to ditch it. Even Apple which claims to stick to standards doesn't go in for certification