# Disable "Charging slowly" warning

Tags: charging, lg

When charging my phone, a LG K8 V, I get the message "Charging slowly: Use the charger and cable that were provided with this phone, or check the cable is properly connected." The charge rate is fast enough for my purposes (I haven't noticed an actual slowdown) and everything's plugged in properly so far as I can see. But, the warning is annoying because it pops up every time I plug in the phone and I need to manually dismiss it to do anything with the phone, even to answer a call. How can I disable it permanently?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: did you charge from usb port?

Comment: @RahulGopi Of a computer? No, I'm charging it from an outlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You will find a good explanation of *charging slowly* in answers to this question [Android phone "charging slowly": How to make it faster](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/143031)
- > ...charge rate is fast enough for my purposes

It is not what *you feel*, it depends on the *power* as you can see from Andrew's answer there. Depending on the power the toast is displayed

- Try methods suggested there to improve charging power. If that doesn't help, there is nothing you can do to prevent the notification from showing up

**Edit:** What finally did work for OP was a thicker Charging cable as was one of the recommendations on the linked answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71990/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-kodiologist).

Comment: Getting a new, thicker cable fixed it (and nothing else did, sadly).

Comment: Good that it worked :)

Comment: My phone gives this warning even with the stock cable it came with.