# Android phone slowly charging message

Tags: usb

I purchased a TCL 10L phone two days ago. To my surprise when I plugged it, the phone said "Fast Charging" and it charged very fast. People on YouTube say that it does not support fast charging. Anyway, on next day, when I emptied the battery, I plugged the charger in. It said something like slowly charging. I panicked and I removed the plug and plugged it back in. It said fast charging like the first time and is currently charging.

I am worried. Is the device displaying the slowly charging message normal? I have 1 day left to replace the device if there are any issues. Though, I am not sure if this is normal or not. The device does not have any faults so far. So, I would risk getting a new device with the same issue and more issues. The port is USB-C if that matters.

Regards and thanks.

Edit: I unplugged the charger at 97%. Then, replugged it. Now, it says "Charging" only. I tried unplugging/replugging two times and still "Charging" no more fast charging at 97%.

Comment: All usb c phones are considered fast charging.

Comment: Your specs says it has a quick charging battery>>>https://www.ubergizmo.com/products/lang/en_us/devices/tcl-10l/

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Though, according to popular sites only the Pro version supports that. https://www.xda-developers.com/tcl-10l-tcl-10-pro-review/ https://www.androidauthority.com/tcl-10-pro-review-1118085/

Comment: Dont believe everything you read.

Comment: In my experience, this could easily be an issue with the charger itself.  Try a different cable, try a different base, if it still happens, you know it's something going on with the phone itself

Comment: Related: [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/143053/44325) to [Android phone “charging slowly”: How to make it faster](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/143031/44325) that explains how Android shows the message.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Andrew T. Though, it does not help me much because this is a brand new phone. Only got it 2-3d ago now. I appreciate it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Slow charging" usually means that the phone wasn't able to confirm that the power source is capable of providing more voltage than the original USB spec allows. This usually happens when the phone is connected to a computer or the cable didn't go all the way in and USB data lines don't contact well. If it doesn't happen too often then it's normal.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using the charger that came with the phone. This is my second charge using the same charger. I am worried. Did you experience this firsthand? I only have one more day and I am into the normal warranty where they repair the phone instead of replacing it.

Comment: @jamana Yes. My current phone sometimes does it with one particular USB type C cable I have. Reversing the cable fixes it. That same phone works fine with other cables and that cable works fine with other phones. Phones check for fast charging capabilities using USB data lines. If these don't make good contact the phone may assume that the power source doesn't support fast charging. Unfortunately I can't say anything about your phone and charger pair. You can try plugging it in for a minute for a few times, in both positions of the cable, and see if it works reliably.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @gronostaj. Is your phone new or semi new, though. I have tried unplugging and replugging the phone several times and it kept saying "Fast Charging" I have tried this 10 times in like 3 minutes. Though, on two of the tries, the phone said "Slow Charging" for just 1/3 of a second and switched to "Fast Charging" right away. At 97%, the I unplugged and replugged the phone 3-4 times and it said "Charging" not "Fast Charging" I do not know if this is normal or not.

Comment: @jamana Slow charging for just a moment, then switching to fast charging is not abnormal. The circuitry sometimes needs a moment to detect charger type. The "regular" charging at 97% kind of makes sense, but I can't tell for sure if it's intentional design or the phone misbehaving in your case.

Comment: I wanted to let you know that I unplugged the phone at around 30% and replugged it and it displayed "Fast Charging" on my three attempts. On one attempt it displayed "Charging" for a fraction of a second and switched to "Fast Charging" I have noticed that the phone displays "Fast Charging" at 98% if I kept it charging from a low level (30% in my case). Though, when I unplugged and replugged it at 98% it said "Charging" only. I have tried this around three times and it always said "Charging" So, there is indeed a pattern. I decided to keep the phone. Thanks again for the information.