# How can I configure a Pixel 6 so that it always charges at max speed?

Tags: charging, google-pixel-6

My Google Pixel 6 phone charges between 3W and 15W with the charger included with the Pixel 6 phone. How can I configure it so that it always charges at max speed? (Or at least whenever I ask for it, eg when I need to it get charged asap before I head out).

Device is not rooted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android phone "charging slowly": How to make it faster](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143031/android-phone-charging-slowly-how-to-make-it-faster)//good answers here to explain why you **can't configure** charging speed

Comment: @beeshyams thanks, in my case the charger and the cable are fine, the issue is that it uses adaptive charging speed, whereas sometimes I don't want adaptive but the fastest speed

Comment: I understand what you want and the answers in the link give reasons why it isn't possible // see [Andrew's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/143053/131553) explaining why you can't configure the charging speed or the notification // If your device was rooted, you could put the device in [idle charging mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/223813/131553) say at around 75% or more

Comment: The other day, I absent mindedly charged my Pixel 4a with a laptop charger and it charged real fast but I wouldn't repeat that much less suggest that as a solution

Comment: Phone batteries (and many others too) are not designed to be charged at a constant rate. There are intelligent charge controllers specifically built into devices to achieve this variable charging rate behavior. There are phases of charging based on the battery level. Battery temperature and current discharge rate also affect the charging rate. So you won't find a genuine solution to what you are looking for. Only some hacks may work. But they are never recommended if you want your device to live longer.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Battery -> Adaptative charging -> turn it off:

[image]

Source: [Reddit - How can I configure a Pixel 6 so that it always charges at max speed?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/yh4xht/how_can_i_configure_a_pixel_6_so_that_it_always/iugiuqx)

Comment: I don't think it's correct 1. [This feature steadily charges your phone over the course of several hours rather than working as quickly as possible to get to 100%](https://www.google.com/amp/s/9to5google.com/2020/12/29/pixel-adaptive-charging/amp/) 2. [you can charge your phone steadily overnight. Adaptive charging uses your alarm’s settings to completely charge your phone right before you wake up](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6090612?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccharge-as-much-or-as-little-as-needed%2Ckeep-adaptive-battery-on%2Chow-to-use-adaptive-charging-pixel-later)

Comment: I think this is what the OP was looking for. Just the question was unclear. // Adaptive Charging saves the battery from the adverse effects of Fast Charging by keeping the charge rate at minimum depending on the time available to fully charge the battery. Turning it off would return to the old normal behavior i.e. max possible speed which is still variable. Still it won't charge at constant max speed.

Comment: This feature is linked to your alarm and ensures that the battery is charged by the time alarm is active. It is **steady** charging to reach full charge NOT **maximum** as asked in the question //Maybe if you set the alarm to run in a short while like 30 minutes it may approx maximum charge but unless it is measured I wouldn't buy this logic

Comment: @IrfanLatif OP clearly asks for **maximum** charging so it's not a matter of misinterpretation